# Calculate number of elements of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(M))$ whose elements themselves are cover ing M

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

Given a set M. Can I easily calculate the number of elements $S_i \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(M))$ such that $\bigcup\limits_{s \in S_i}s = M$?

For example, $M = \{A,B\}$. Then the number of elements of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(M))$ meeting that condition would be 10: there are $2^{2^2} = 16$ elements, every element except for $\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{A\}, \{B\}, \{\emptyset, A\}, \{\emptyset, B\}$ has $A$ **and** $B$ in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very nice question. You can determine this number using inclusion-exclusion. Denote $|M|$ by $n$, and consider the $n$ conditions of a particular element missing from the union. Then by inclusion-exclusion the desired count is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(-1)^k2^{2^{n-k}}\;.
$$

In your example with $n=2$, this is $2^{2^2}-2\cdot2^{2^1}+2^{2^0}=16-8+2=10$.

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A000371](https://oeis.org/A000371).

Comment: Wow thank you both very much. This was exactly what I was looking for. I'm pretty happy right now :)

Comment: To be honest, I don't really get it. For each $m \in M$, let $A_m$ denote the set of all $X \in \mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ such that $m \notin \bigcup X.$ Okay, now what?

Comment: @goblin: That gives you the $k=1$ term: There are $\binom n1$ choices for $m$, and $|A_m|=2^{2^{n-1}}$ for all $m$. Then you need to do the same thing for any $B\subseteq M$ with $|B|=k$; there are $\binom nk$ choices of $B$, and $2^{2^{n-k}}$ elements of $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(X))$ whose union is disjoint from $B$.

Comment: @Alex: There were no "both"; I added the OEIS comment myself when it later occurred to me :-) I'm glad you're happy :-)

Comment: @joriki, okay, thanks.

Comment: Yeah I saw that, but it was too late to edit it :(